# Не работает вызов метода внутри класса

Tags: php

При вызове `fun_2` ничего не происходит. В чем может быть проблема?

```
class main {
  public function fun_1($string) {
    return fun_2($string);
  }
  function fun_2($string) {
    return gettype($string);
  }
}
```

Comment: как это ничего не происходит? вы в логи загляните или отображение ошибок включите, там будет что-то вроде "вызов неопределенной функции fun_2", ибо вызывать надо `$this->fun_2()`

Comment: `$this->fun_2();`

Comment: @teran благодарю! Как то я упустил этот момент, надо повнимательнее читать)